# Static variable initialization order in C++: Why is the output of 'j' equal to 3 in this code?

Tags: c++, static

I have the following C++ code that initializes a static variable notreR of class R and an integer variable j that is also a member of class R. However, when I initialize j to 0 after initializing notreR, j still has a value of 3 at the end of the code. I want to know why the initialization order of j and notreR does not matter.

Edit:
I was having a problem understanding the difference between the dynamic and the static initialization and the answer was from Igor Tandetnik in the comments

> You seem to expect R* R::notreR = new R(0); to run first, increment j (from which value? If you believe j wasn't initialized yet, then what do you believe j++ should produce?), and then int R::j = 0; would run and reset j to zero. This is not how it works. See also this article, and in particular the distinction between static and dynamic initialization

here's the output:

```
r2 = R, i = 2
monR = NULL
r1 = R, i = 1
monR = R, i = 2
R:: notreR = R, i = 0
monR = R, i = 1
R::j = 3
```

here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>




using namespace std;



class R{
    public:
    static R* notreR;
    static int j;
    int i;
    R* monR;
    R(int a){
        i = a;
        monR=NULL;

        j++;
    }
    static void p(R* r){
        j=0;
        notreR = new R(0);
        m(notreR);
    }
    static void q(R* r){
        cout << "R:: notreR = ";
        m(notreR);
        cout << "monR = ";
        if(notreR->monR!=NULL) 
        notreR->monR->m(notreR->monR);
        else cout << "NULL" << endl;
        cout << "R::j = " << j << endl;
    }

    static void m(R* r){
        cout << "R, i = " << r->i << endl;
    }

    static void n(R* r){
        m(r);
        cout << "monR = ";
        if(r->monR!=NULL) 
        r->monR->m(r->monR);
        else cout << "NULL" << endl;
    }


    };

    R* R::notreR = new R(0);
    
    int R::j = 0;

    


    class S{
        public:
        static void main(){
            R* r1 = new R(1);
            R::notreR->monR = r1;
            R* r2 = new R(2);
            cout << "r2 = ";
            
            R::n(r2);
            r1->monR = r2; 
            cout << "r1 = ";
            R::n(r1); 
            R::q(r1); 
        }
    };
int main(){
    
    S::main();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the code? What is your assignment or exercise? Why do you need to use all those static member variables and functions? What is the actual and underlying problem the code is supposed to solve?

Comment: the code is an exercise given by my professor, and the purpose is to understand the concept of static member variables and functions in C++, I found it in her last year's exam, I'm supposed to manually execute this code and return the output

Comment: I can't believe this is actually C++ homework given to students.  No one in the real world writes such code, let alone attempt to understand what it's doing.

Comment: When you say "I assign 0 to `j`", are you talking about `int R::j = 0;`? This is initialization, not assignment. Being a static initialization, it happens first (in practice, it doesn't involve any code being executed; the variable `R::j` has the value 0 as soon as the executable is loaded into memory). In contrast, `R* R::notreR = new R(0);` is dynamic initialization; it happens before `main`, but after static initialization.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes, I meant initialize

Comment: You seem to expect `R* R::notreR = new R(0);` to run first, increment `j` (from which value? If you believe `j` wasn't initialized yet, then what do you believe `j++` should produce?), and then `int R::j = 0;` would run and reset `j` to zero. This is not how it works. See also [this article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization), and in particular the distinction between static and dynamic initialization.

Comment: then, the order does not matter? initializing notreR will increment j to 1, that's what happened?

Comment: The order of these two particular lines indeed doesn't matter, as they fall into two distinct phases of initialization, and one phase (static) always happens before the other (dynamic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is the output of 'j' equal to 3 in this code?

It's because you've use the `R(int)` constructor 3 times before `j` is printed.

First, the `static` `R*`:

```cpp
R* R::notreR = new R(0); // j == 1
```

Then two times in `S::main`:

```
R* r1 = new R(1);        // j == 2
R::notreR->monR = r1;
R* r2 = new R(2);        // j == 3
```